# Firefox laggy canvas on start

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, canvas

I'm creating my company site at this address http://odstrony.pl/nowa_strona/ . I'm having problems with my custom preloader (rendered on canvas element with request animation frame). On all browsers except for firefox it works at approx 50 fps. What do I have to do in order to render my preloader at aprox 50 fps in firefox (the problem appears when all history and cache for site is cleared)?

EDIT

this is request anim cross-browser code:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
            function( callback ){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
})();
window.cancelRequestAnimFrame = ( function(){
    return window.cancelAnimationFrame          ||
        window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame       ||
        window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame     ||
        window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame        ||
        clearTimeout
})();
```

this is my preload code:

```
function preload(element,element_glowny){
    var self = this;

    this.frameCount = 0;
    this.fps = 60;
    this.fpsInterval;
    this.startTime;
    this.now;
    this.then;
    this.elapsed;

    this.podniesienie = 0;

    this.element_glowny = element_glowny;
    this.ctx = element.getContext("2d");
    this.ctx_width = element.width;
    this.ctx_height = element.height;


    this.logo_svg_xml;
    this.colorLogo;
    this.logo_height = 350;
    this.logo_width = 350;

    this.fala_svg_xml;
    this.colorFali;
    this.fala_height = 69;
    this.fala_width = 500;
    this.fala_x = 0;
    this.fala_y = 0;

    this.wysokosc_wody = 0;

    this.idz_w_prawo = true;

    this.fala_zakres_x_min = -100;
    this.fala_zakres_x_max = 500;

    this.ilosc_zdjec;
    this.ilosc_zdjec_zaladowanych = 0;

    this.animacjaReferencja;

    this.start = function(){

        this.fpsInterval = 1000 / this.fps;
        this.then = Date.now();
        this.startTime = this.then;

        //ustawianie startowej wysokosci
        this.fala_y = this.logo_height-this.fala_height;
        this.ilosc_zdjec = $("img").size();

        this.initSVGColors("#FFFFFF","#3B71B8");
        //this.render();
        this.glownaPetla();
    }

    this.glownaPetla = function(){
        self.animacjaReferencja = requestAnimFrame(self.glownaPetla);

        self.now = Date.now();
        self.elapsed = self.now - self.then;

        if (self.elapsed > self.fpsInterval) {
            self.then = self.now - (self.elapsed % self.fpsInterval);

            //render
            self.kontrolaFali();
            self.render();
        }
    }

    this.initSVGColors = function(colorFali,colorLogo){
        this.colorFali = colorFali;
        this.colorLogo = colorLogo;
        this.logo_svg_xml = '<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="350px" height="350px" viewBox="0 0 350 350" enable-background="new 0 0 350 350" xml:space="preserve"> <g> <path fill="'+colorLogo+'" d="M112.207,90.146c5.859-4.237,12.249-7.937,19.273-11.008c12.926-5.631,27.497-8.446,43.72-8.446 c16.208,0,30.711,2.815,43.511,8.446c12.776,5.644,23.682,13.259,32.677,22.864c8.991,9.603,15.896,20.693,20.718,33.233 c4.803,12.554,7.219,25.875,7.219,39.96c0,13.71-2.391,26.788-7.114,39.235c19.878,13.509,40.154,26.502,60.672,38.722 c1.743-3.759,3.496-7.506,5.001-11.444C345.946,220.666,350,198.529,350,175.315c0-23.608-4.054-45.958-12.117-67.021 c-8.072-21.051-19.653-39.643-34.737-55.756c-15.095-16.098-33.38-28.904-54.819-38.364C226.846,4.738,202.511,0,175.326,0 c-27.207,0-51.642,4.739-73.323,14.175c-16.436,7.175-30.975,16.305-43.627,27.31C74.636,56.744,92.683,73.131,112.207,90.146z"/> <path fill="'+colorLogo+'" d="M183.131,349.828c-0.448-19.223-3.971-42.534-12.35-70.697c-14.435-0.479-27.577-3.149-39.301-8.252 c-12.915-5.645-23.873-13.273-32.869-22.882c-8.998-9.587-15.901-20.677-20.712-33.231c-4.811-12.546-7.225-25.742-7.225-39.569 c0-14.084,2.414-27.406,7.225-39.959c3.32-8.653,7.706-16.575,13.021-23.826C78.901,91.801,65.477,71.068,50.426,49.114 c-1.166,1.165-2.445,2.229-3.569,3.425C31.764,68.651,20.19,87.244,12.113,108.294C4.028,129.357,0,151.707,0,175.315 c0,23.214,4.028,45.351,12.113,66.393c8.077,21.064,19.65,39.652,34.743,55.758c15.08,16.103,33.478,28.899,55.147,38.337 C123.687,345.262,148.122,350,175.326,350C177.965,350,180.55,349.913,183.131,349.828z"/> </g> </svg>';
        this.fala_svg_xml = '<svg version="1.1" id="Isolation_Mode" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="500.297px" height="69.069px" viewBox="170.798 262.645 500.297 69.069" enable-background="new 170.798 262.645 500.297 69.069" xml:space="preserve"> <path fill="'+colorFali+'" d="M671.094,332.636v-35.008c0,0-53.763,34.463-125.074,34.983c-71.313-0.52-125.074-34.983-125.074-34.983 s-53.762-34.464-125.074-34.983c-71.313,0.52-125.074,34.983-125.074,34.983v35.008H671.094z"/> </svg>';
    }

    this.kontrolaFali = function(){

        this.fala_x+=8;



        if(this.ilosc_zdjec_zaladowanych != this.ilosc_zdjec){
            this.ilosc_zdjec_zaladowanych = 0;

            $("img").each( function(){
                self.ilosc_zdjec_zaladowanych += 1;
                if (this.naturalWidth === 0 || this.naturalHeight === 0 || this.complete === false) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            var procent_zaladowania = this.ilosc_zdjec_zaladowanych/this.ilosc_zdjec*100;
            this.wysokosc_wody = (procent_zaladowania/100)*this.ctx_height-this.fala_height;
            this.podniesienie = this.ctx_height-this.wysokosc_wody-this.fala_height;

        }

        //podnoszenie fali
        if(this.fala_y+this.fala_height > this.podniesienie){
            this.fala_y -= 10;
        }
        //zakonczenie animacji
        if((this.fala_y+this.fala_height-this.fala_height).toFixed(0) == -this.fala_height){
            cancelRequestAnimFrame(this.animacjaReferencja);
            this.element_glowny.addClass("schowaj");
                $(".dynamiczny_tekst h1:last-child span").typed({
                    strings: ["PoczÄtku", "Strony"],
                    typeSpeed: 150,
                    cursorChar: "|"
                });
            setTimeout( function(){
                self.element_glowny.css({"z-index":"-1"});
            }, 300);
        }


    }

    this.render = function(){

        this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.ctx_width,this.ctx_height);

        this.renderLogo(this.ctx);

        this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";

        this.renderFala(this.ctx);

        this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

        this.renderNapis(this.ctx);


    }

    this.renderLogo = function(ctx){
        ctx.transform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

        ctx.drawSvg(this.logo_svg_xml, 0, 0, this.logo_width, this.logo_height);

        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    }

    this.renderNapis = function(ctx){
        ctx.transform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

        ctx.font="13px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif";
        ctx.fillText((((this.ctx_height-this.fala_y-this.fala_height)/this.ctx_height)*100).toFixed(0)+"%",155,170);

        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    }

    this.renderFala = function(ctx){

        if(this.fala_x > 500){
            this.fala_x = 0;
        }

        ctx.transform(1,0,0,1,this.fala_x,this.fala_y);

        ctx.drawSvg(this.fala_svg_xml, 0, 0, this.fala_width, this.fala_height);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.colorFali;
        ctx.fillRect(0,this.fala_height,this.fala_width,this.ctx_height*2);

        ctx.transform(1,0,0,1,-this.fala_width,0);

        ctx.drawSvg(this.fala_svg_xml, 0, 0, this.fala_width, this.fala_height);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.colorFali;
        ctx.fillRect(0,this.fala_height,this.fala_width,this.ctx_height*2);

        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

    }

}
//preload
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var loading = new preload(document.getElementById("loading-image"),$("#preload"));
    loading.start();
});
```

Comment: maybe post some code... nice site btw

Comment: in my edit i post the code. Thanks! btw. :)

Comment: Have you tried it on various machines. Each browser handles hardware a little different, it may just be a quirk FF has with the particular GPU you are using. Also the SVG is SLOW, as you are not changing the resolution of the displayed SVG consider rendering it to a off screen canvas and then just rendering the bitmap unless you have animation in it that is.